# Image will build from docker run but not docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Been trying for hours to figure out why `docker run -p 3000:3000` will successfully run my image but not `docker-compose up` . When I run the former command the routing for my app works and I can visit the URL in the browser. However when I use the latter command the browser returns me an nginx 404 error.

Dockerfile:

```
#Base Image node:12.18.4-alpine
FROM node:12.18.4-alpine


#Set working directory to /app
WORKDIR /InboundBackend


#Set PATH /app/node_modules/.bin
ENV PATH /InboundBackend/node_modules/.bin:$PATH


#Copy package.json in the image
COPY package.json ./


RUN npm install
RUN npm ci --only-production
#Copy the app
COPY . /InboundBackend/

EXPOSE 3000

##Start the app
# CMD ["ls"]
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Nginx Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx
COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  nodejs:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: nodejs
    container_name: nodejs
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

  nginx:
    image: nginx:mainline-alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: ./nginx-conf
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
```

My nginx configuration:

```
    listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;


        #location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
         #       allow all;
         #      root /var/www/html;
        #}

        #location / {
        #        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri? permanent;
        #}

        location /graphql {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://nodejs:3000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }

        #location @Nodejs {
         #       proxy_pass http://Nodejs:3000;
         #      add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
         #     add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
         #       add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
         #       add_header Referrer-Policy "no-referrer-when-downgrade" always;
         #       add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src * data: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'" always;
        #}

}
server {
       #  listen 443 ssl http2;
        # listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
        server_name api.***.com www.api.***.com;

        server_tokens off;

        # ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/nodejs.devopslee.com/fullchain.pem;
        # ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/nodejs.devopslee.com/privkey.pem;

        ssl_buffer_size 8k;



        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

        ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1;
        ssl_session_tickets off;

        ssl_stapling on;
        ssl_stapling_verify on;
        resolver 8.8.8.8;


        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
}
```

When I run `docker-compose up` the nodejs server runs the same way and I can see all the server logging. Again it's just that the endpoints are unreachable

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why you have `image` in the `docker-compose.yaml` if the `build` is specified?

Comment: Please post code as text and not as images!

Comment: Also can you give us more details of the docker run case? In the compose file there are 2 services. How are you starting the nginx service without docker-compose? The `build.context` for your nginx service does nothing, as the nginx image is not built. This means the nginx you are running with docker-compose has the standard configuration and it won't forward anything.

Comment: @Garuno Sorry, been a long night didn't even realize what I was doing. I removed the images. I just run `docker run -p 3000:3000 nodejs` after editing my conf file under `etc/nginx` and it was working

Comment: @Garuno I have another Dockerfile for the `nginx` service, ill edit it in sorry. I was actually following this tutorial: https://ashwin9798.medium.com/nginx-with-docker-and-node-js-a-beginners-guide-434fe1216b6b

Comment: Can you remove both the `image:` parts from the docker-compose file? They don't make sense, if you build the images with `build:`. This could be the cause of the problem

Comment: What's in default.conf?

Comment: @Garuno That didn't work either unfortunately, I added my nginx config too

Comment: Are you sure that the nginx container is correctly built? Check if the default.conf is in the container `docker exec webserver cat /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf`. Your config also looks broken,